# Why does this method not prevent NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables, will-paginate

I'm using the will_paginate gem, and trying to implement DataTables, per this RailsCast, and discovered that it is a good idea to supply the attribute total_entries, because will_paginate apparently does not do this very well.

So I added this method to my class like so:

```
class Genotype < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :allele1, :allele2, :run_date
  belongs_to :gmarkers
  belongs_to :gsamples

  def total_entries
    @t = Genotype.count;
    return @t
  end

end
```

However, I still get this error when the view tries to load (this is a screenshot of the webserver responses):

```
   (7.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "genotypes" 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 96ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `total_entries' for nil:NilClass):
  app/datatables/genotypes_datatable.rb:13:in `as_json'
  app/controllers/genotypes_controller.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/genotypes_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Obviously I must be doing something wrong in defining my method; but what? I am too inexperienced in Rails to stumble my way out of this...

Thanks in advance,

Rick

Comment: It has nothing to do with the method, it has to do with calling it on nil.

Comment: If you could explain how I should define total_entries such that it corrects the error, that would be more helpful...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the method. The problem is that it's being called on a `nil` object. In other words, you're basically saying `nil.total_entries`, and there is no `total_entries` call that makes sense if it's called on nothing. The issue is not in the code you posted, it's in the serialization.

Comment: Thanks Dave; that's helps somewhat. My real goal is to get DataTables to work, based on the example provided by RailsCast 340...but that's another post...